# Can I do a static import of a private subclass?

Tags: java, syntax, enums, static-import

I have an enum which is private, not to be exposed outside of the class. Is there anyway I can do a static import of that type, so that I don't have to type the enum type each time?  Or is there a better way to write this?  Example:

```
package kip.test;

import static kip.test.Test.MyEnum.*; //compile error

public class Test
{
  private static enum MyEnum { DOG, CAT }

  public static void main (String [] args)
  {
    MyEnum dog = MyEnum.DOG; //this works but I don't want to type "MyEnum"
    MyEnum cat = CAT; //compile error, but this is what I want to do
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or is there a better way to write this?

If your main goals are to reference the items without their qualifying enum identifier, and maintain this list privately, you could scrap the `enum` type altogether and use ordinary private static constants.

Comment: no, enum provides other forms of safety other than just encapsulation - for example, you can use them in switch statements, and you can get warnings if you omit one. Just stick with the qualifier - there are worse verbosity problems in java ;)

Comment: @akf: Chii's right, in my actual code the enums have some behavior beyond what can be trivially done with static constants. I just simplified all that out for the question so it would be the bare minimum example. I guess I'm just stuck with long qualifier names (much longer than "`MyEnum`" in my actual code unfortunately...)

Answer (score 10):

You can use the no-modifier access level, i.e.

```
enum MyEnum { DOG, CAT }
```

`MyEnum` will not be visible to classes from other packages neither from any subclass. It is the closest form of private, yet letting you avoid explicitly referencing `MyEnum`.

Comment: The problem I have with this approach is that it is confusing (or perhaps 'surprising') - I've just spent a while in a code review working out why the developer had imported an enum other than the Enum in the class; they hadn't but that's what it looked like because I wasn't reading the import properly: I thought we'd accidentally either created two identically-named classes in subtly-different packages. At least using MyEnum.DOG removes the need for the import and reduces the potential for confusion.

Answer (score 5):

Considering that you can access the field fully qualified, I would say that it is a bug in the compiler (or language spec) that you cannot statically import it.

I suggest that you make the enumeration package-protected.

Answer (score 3):

It may (or may not) be reasonable to move some of the code into (static) methods of the enum.

If pressed, you could duplicate the static fields in the outer class.

```
private static final MyEnum CAT = MyEnum.CAT;
private static final MyEnum DOG = MyEnum.DOG;
```

Icky, but a possibility.

Comment: Yeah I thought of this too. I guess it's either this or just using the qualified name. Neither is ideal, but I think using the qualified name will be less error-prone at least.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply write your code inside the enum itself.

```
public enum MyEnum {
DOG, CAT;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyEnum dog = MyEnum.DOG; // this works but I don't want to have to type
                                // MyEnum
    MyEnum cat = CAT; // compile error, but this is what I want to do
}
 }
```

The other place where private enums can be references without their class is in a switch statement:

```
private static enum MyEnum {
    DOG, CAT
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyEnum e = null;
    switch (e) {
    case DOG:
    case CAT:
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope, that's pretty much what `private` is all about.

Comment: On the other hand, the outer class can access all private fields and method directly. So the case could be made for wanting to import it.